# can we change the value of a variable stored within another variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

There is a variable let say `var content` which holds some HTML content and this HTML also contains a JavaScript variable let say `${id}`. Now I want to update the value of `${id}` variable. I have tried with the following code but it's not working.

```
var id = '';
var content = `<div class="row well margin_btm_ten">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <b>ID is ${id}</b>  
    </div>`;
row_id = 2;
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(content)
});
```

Comment: `row_id` you have never used that.

Comment: No, you cannot just change `id` and have it reflected in `content`. You will need to explicitly re-build `content` when changing `id`.

Comment: This is pretty much what functions are for.

Comment: or use replace function like content.replace("${id}", id);

Comment: @Arjit This is the template literal syntax. "${id}" doesn't exist in the string anymore.

Comment: @JJJ some reference will be there which can use for replace

Comment: @Arjit No there isn't. `id` is specifically an empty string in the OP's code so there's literally nothing left of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can have content be a function that returns the html content, so that it will calculate it every time it's called. This way if the id variable changes, the value returned by content() will also change:

```js
var id = 'one';
var content = () => `<div class="row well margin_btm_ten">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <b>ID is ${id}</b>  
    </div>`;
console.log(content());
id = 'two';
console.log(content());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible since the reference to "content" is being created with the current value of the variable `id`. JavaScript variables are basically containers for storing data values. You would need to "rerun" the `content` variable, to get the new `id`. But I think you should rather use functions than overwriting variables.

```js
const printName = (name => console.log(`Hello ${name}`));

let name = "Mark";

printName(name);

name = "Peter";

printName(name);
```

Comment: Using a custom setter is a nice example for the usage of this Javascript feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `id` a function with *custom setter for `id` property* which will make `content` update every time you set a new `id`.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

```js
function id() {
  var id;
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', {
    get() {
      return id;
    },
    set(value) {
      id = value;
      content = `<div class="row well margin_btm_ten">
          <div class="col-md-1">
              <b>ID is ${id}</b>  
          </div>`;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
};

var obj = new id();

var content = `<div class="row well margin_btm_ten">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <b>ID is ${obj.id}</b>  
    </div>`;

console.log(content) // id: undefined

app.innerHTML += content

obj.id = 2;

console.log(content) // id: 2

app.innerHTML += content

obj.id = 'Hello World!';

console.log(content) // id: 'Hello World'

app.innerHTML += content
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: basically not bad at all. But IMHO much overengineering for a fn that should return a text based on the args.